# How to share in Google+ without opening share dialog

Tags: share, google-plus, oneclick

I am going to develop an extention to share a selected part of page just by clicking on a share image that shown in page..How can I share a text or image in google plus without opening share dialog?
Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to share on Google+ is through the share dialog.

Comment: Thanks for you help.Can I write a code that automaticly submit share dialogs form and close it?Is this posible?

Comment: You'll want to take a look at this code snippet: https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/#sharelink

Answer (score 1):

Google has stated that they want shares to be deliberate actions - they don't want to allow web pages or other systems to be able to post anything "on your behalf" without the user taking a specific affirmative action.

In short, they don't want Facebook's "frictionless sharing".

They are beginning to roll out the ability for websites to automatically post "moments" into a history vault, but users will still need to take a specific action for these moments to be posted to their stream. See https://developers.google.com/+/history/ for more information and the developer preview.